# ¿Cómo ejecutar PhantomJS desde PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, linux, phantomjs

Necesito crear una funcionalidad que me retorne la última redirección dentro de un conjunto de redirecciones. Para lograr esto yo dispongo de una función PHP, sin embargo, no me sirve para los casos de aquellas urls cuyas redirecciones son realizadas desde JS, porque PHP no ejecuta JS.

Me han recomendado usar un *headless browser*, por lo que he descargado e instalado *PhantomJS*. Además, he ejecutado los ejemplos básicos de la documentación y funciona a la perfección.

Ya que *PhantomJS* se ejecuta en la línea de comandos, invocarlo desde PHP bastaría con añadir simplemente la siguiente línea al script

```
exec('/usr/local/bin/phantomjs path/somescript.js');
```

Ahora bien, **¿Qué debo hacer para recibir la respuesta de phantomjs?**

**¿Qué configuraciones debo realizar para que me devuelva la última URL?**

Comment: Te sugiero que utilices [un cliente PHP para PhantomJS](https://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/), porque ejecutarlo todo desde llamadas a procesos del sistema puede traerte muchos dolores de cabeza.

Comment: Leí sobre un cliente, pero está en desuso actualmente. Además de lo mencionado anteriormente, leí que no es compatible con las últimas versiones de PhantomJS ¿es correcto?

Comment: Sí, eso parece. Puedes reemplazar PhantomJS por [Headless Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Headless_mode) o  [Headless Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) usando Selenium. Hay [un cliente PHP](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver), pero nunca lo he usado.  PhantomJS ya no se usa, ya que las soluciones Headless son mucho más estables al estar soportadas por los navegadores más populares.